# Difference between char , char[] , char *

Tags: c++

I tried to set simple char with empty value without success. The main goal was to compare between std::string single char and pre-defined char

```
std::string str ="fcvfr";
char c = '' //trying to set empty char here ....  but it gives me error
if(c == str[0]) 
{
   //do something 
}
```

This leads me to the question when should I use each of the following types:

```
char * , char , char[]
```

Comment: I may be stating the obvious, but shouldn't f be 'f' (with single quotes)?

Comment: Also, you're missing a semicolon. And if _"it gives [you] error"_ it would be nice of you to specify exactly _what_ error you're getting.

Comment: What do you mean by "empty char"? A character always has a value. And what is `f`? Did you mean the character constant `'f'`? What is the error you get, and do you still get it if you add the missing `;`?

Comment: What do you want to know? I cannot see any connection between the last sentence and former sentents.

Comment: i fixed it it meant to be empty char , how can i set empty char into 
char variable , sorry

Comment: @user63898 There's no such thing as an empty `char`.  A `char` always contains exactly one character (or more precisely, exactly one small integral value usually interpreted to be a single byte character, or part of a multi-byte character).  An empty string is either an `std::string` with a size of 0, or a `const char*` pointing to a `'\0'`.

Comment: @user63898 There's no such thing as an empty char. A char is just one byte in memory - if you want to initialize it to zero, do `char c = '\0'` or `char c = (char) 0`.

Comment: @user63898 And of course, you should never use `char*` or `char[]` except when interfacing legacy code (and even then, the `char*` will usually come from something like `&buffer[0]`, where `buffer` is a `std::vector<char>`).

Comment: @JamesKanze Sorry for my earlier comment which was very similar to yours, I was writing it at the same time. @user63898 And if you really need to explicitly allocate an array of chars on the heap (rather than a string), don't use `new`, look into smart pointers with C++11 (or Boost before C++11).

Comment: @mga If you really need to explicitly allocate an array of `char` on the heap, use `std::vector<char>`.  (In pre-C++11, I did this a lot, because `std::string` didn't guarantee contiguity.  In C++11, I'd just use `std::string` most of the time.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Agreed. I just wanted to point out never to use a raw `new`, as I suspect the OP comes from a Java/C# background where `new` is actually similar to smart pointers in C++ and not to `new`. But @user63898, yes, by all means, use `std::vector<char>` or better still `std::string`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`char` represents a character (allocated on the stack). If you want to set it to empty, use `char c = '\0'` or `char c = (char) 0`.

`char* cPtr` is a pointer to a character. You can allocate an empty character on the heap with `char* c = new char('\0')`.

`char c[n]` is a character array of size `n`.

---

**Edit**

As people have correctly pointed out below, a `char` is never empty, in the same sense as a container such as `std::vector` or `std::string` can be empty. A `char` is not fundamentally different to, say, an `int`, it's just shorter (1 byte as opposed to 2 or 4 or 8). Can an `int` be empty? Not as such; it can be zero, meaning that all its bits are set to zero in memory, and the same goes for a char. `char c = '\0'` will be represented as "00000000" on the stack.

A pointer to a char (`char* cPtr`), on the other hand can be 'empty' in the sense that it can point nowhere, by setting it to `NULL`. In this case, the pointer itself will exist on the stack and will contain a special sequence of 0/1's that your system interprets as `NULL`. Once you do `cPtr = new char('\0')`, a `char` (i.e. a byte) will be allocated on the heap and set to "00000000", and the value of `cPtr` on the stack will be changed to point to the address of the new character on the heap.

PS: don't actually do `char* cPtr = new char('\0')`, use an `std::vector<char>` or an `std::string`. Also, you may want to look into [smart pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one).

Comment: The null terminator is not the same as "empty".

Comment: In memory, the character's bytes will be initialized to zero. That's as close to "empty" as I can think of for a character. Of course a pointer can be set to NULL, but I don't think that's what the OP meant (but not sure).

Comment: A `char` is never empty.  A string (regardless of its representation) can be empty, but a `char` is always exactly one character (or a part of one character, if e.g. you're using UTF-8).